# enabled systemd service not starting

Tags: systemd

I have two systemd services, one is a flask app meant to proxy calls to a C backend.
While the flask app works the C program does not start at boot.

My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my backend
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/home/root/camtool
Type=dbus
BusName=com.camera
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
```

and i have enabled the service like this:
`systemctl enable camtool.service`

The service starts if i do a `systemctl start camtool.service` but if i reboot the device, the service is not started.

output of `systemctl status camtool`:

```
● camtool.service - my backend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/camtool.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

If i check journalctl, there are no entries.

```
journalctl -u camtool
-- Logs begin at Wed 2021-07-14 14:12:26 UTC, end at Wed 2021-07-14 14:16:26 UTC. --
-- No entries --
```

I am unsure how to debug this further, as there does not seem to be any error messages.
How can i proceed to figure out why the program didn't start? is there a way i can verify if it was even attempted?

The C program use DBUS to expose functions for the flask app, and stream data via sockets.

Comment: I assume you also have an `[Install]` section; can you include that in your post?

Comment: Hey jeff.
I do not at this point, i used to have
```
[Install]
wantedby=multi-user.target
```
and have ```after=dbus```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems i fixed the problem by re enabling the service.
I had made many changes to try and fix the file, but when i disabled and re enabled i realised the symlink was in the wrong place.

By disabling and enabling this was fixed.
I would recommend to disable and re enable when ever changes are made to the areas concerning targets.

Before i did that i added the `wantedby=multi-user.target`.

The commands looked like this:

```
root@system:~# systemctl disable camtool
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user-target.service.wants/camtool.service.
root@system:~# systemctl enable camtool
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/camtool.service → /etc/systemd/system/camtool.service.
```

Now it boots with the system.

Comment: In my case, I neglected to enable it in the first place.